# Remover Cookie ao fechar o navegador

Tags: javascript, cookies

Quando a aplicação é iniciada, preciso abrir uma modal para o usuário escolher um ambiente, então criei um **cookie** em **JS** para armazenar se é a primeira vez que o usuário abriu a aplicação, segue o codigo:

```
 window.onload = function() {

        var cookies = document.cookie;

        // Verifica se o cookie existe
        if (cookies.indexOf("usuarioVisualizouModal") == -1) {
            // Entra aqui caso o cookie não exista no  navegador do usuário

            // Crio um objeto Date do Javascript pegando a data de hoje e incrementando + 14 dias nessa data
            var diasparaexpirar = 14;
            var expiracao = new Date();
            expiracao.setTime(expiracao.getTime() + (diasparaexpirar * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

            // Converte a data para string
            expiracao = expiracao.toUTCString();

            // Crio o cookie com a data de expiração
            document.cookie = 'usuarioVisualizouModal=SIM;  path=/';

            // Exibo o modal
            var url = '/Facility/ActiveFacility';
            $('#ModalBody').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
            $("#OpenModal").modal("show");
        }
    };
```

Não tenho experiencia com cookies, dei uma estudada sobre e peguei esse codigo de exemplo. No codigo ele expira o cookie em 14 dias, eu preciso que o cookie seja expirado quando a aplicação é fechada. Tentei utilizar o "Onunload" no body do layout, porém ele não exibe a tela de seleção ao abrir a aplicação novamente, não sei se ele esta realmente deletando o cookie. Segue o codigo que usei no onunload:

Codigo no Body:

```
<body onunload="deleteCookie(usuarioVisualizouModal);">
```

Função:

```
         function deleteCookie(nome){
   var exdate = new Date();
   exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + (-1 * 24 * 3600
      * 1000));
   document.cookie = nome + "=" + escape("")+ ((-1
      == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate);
 }
```

Alguma solução ?

ps: quando utilizei o OnUnload eu removi o Expirate do codigo que gera o cookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É impossivel garantir que isto ocorra, ainda mais se o usuário usar o manter "sessão", quando reabre o navegador as abas são restauradas ao ultimo estado, por exemplo nos navegadores atuais (13/08/2018):

Opera:

[image: opera manter sessão]

Chrome:

[image: chrome manter sessão]

Ou seja, o navegador vai tentar manter tudo neste ponto, como se o usuário nem tivesse fechado, então a melhor saída é trabalhar com tempo mesmo, e colocar um tempo limite para expirar o cookie

Comment: Entendi, eu consegui fazer aquela função funcionar apenas colocando aspas no onunload, ele não tava reconhecendo o nome do cookie, ai agora sempre que o navegador fecha e abre dnv, ele incializa o cookie, mas realmente essa questão que vc falou deve ser considerada

Comment: @DanOliveira o problema de onunload é que ele também não é garantido, ainda mais se o usuário "matar" o processo principal, que fecharia tudo, por exemplo fazer logoff, ou esta usando em um celular aonde geralmente é possivel finalizar tudo sem confirmação, quando fecha o app de navegador

Comment: Entendi, valeu pela ajuda Brother! Vou manter por tempo mesmo, mais garantido